# scraping table from xml

Tags: r, xml, rvest, rselenium

http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputbyFuelHourly/PUB_GenOutputbyFuelHourly.xml

I tried this using rvest --

```
 url <-"http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputbyFuelHourly/PUB_GenOutputbyFuelHourly.xml"



url %>%
read_html() %>%
 html_nodes("table") %>% html_table()
```

That didn't work, so next I tried using in conjunction with selectorgadget --

```
url %>%
read_html() %>%
 html_nodes(".report td") %>% html_table()
```

And no dice there, either. I have some experience with Rselenium and was able to hack out the following solution:

```
library(RSelenium)

remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "phantomjs")
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate(url)
css <- paste0(".report td")
webElems <- remDr$findElements("css", css)
values <- unlist(sapply(webElems, function(x){x$getElementText()}))
```

where "values" is now a vector with each entry in the table, left-to-right and top-to-bottom. I could then basically parse this into a table - i.e each 9 entries form one row.

However, this is just messy, and I'd like to be able to pull this down as a dataframe if at all possible. Any advice appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Lastly, I do know that I used the html_ functions rather than the xml_ functions in rvest - i did it simply because there is no xml_table function. I'm not too sharp on HTML in general, so if somebody could shed some light on the differences here I'd appreciate that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When called without identifying you're a browser, it just returns a raw XML file. It's a well-formatted XML file, so it's very straighforward to process (albeit a bit painstaking to get the nested records).

The following generates a "long" data frame from the XML directly:

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

doc <- read_xml("http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputbyFuelHourly/PUB_GenOutputbyFuelHourly.xml")

doc <- xml_ns_strip(doc) # this just reduces XPath query string complexities
```

The data is "nested" so we just need to "unnest" it:

```
xml_find_all(doc, ".//DailyData") %>%
  map_df(~{
    xml_find_all(.x, ".//HourlyData") %>% 
      map_df(~{
        xml_find_all(.x, ".//FuelTotal") %>% 
          map_df(~{
            data_frame(
              fuel = xml_text(xml_find_first(.x, ".//Fuel"), trim=TRUE),
              output = xml_double(xml_find_first(.x, ".//Output"))
            )
          }) %>% 
          mutate(hour = xml_double(xml_find_first(.x, ".//Hour")))
      }) %>% 
      mutate(day = as.Date(xml_text(xml_find_first(.x, ".//Day"), trim=TRUE)))
  })
## # A tibble: 2,448 x 4
##       fuel output  hour        day
##      <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>     <date>
##  1 NUCLEAR  11671     1 2018-01-01
##  2     GAS   1583     1 2018-01-01
##  3   HYDRO   4152     1 2018-01-01
##  4    WIND    992     1 2018-01-01
##  5   SOLAR      0     1 2018-01-01
##  6 BIOFUEL      3     1 2018-01-01
##  7 NUCLEAR  11672     2 2018-01-01
##  8     GAS   1192     2 2018-01-01
##  9   HYDRO   4093     2 2018-01-01
## 10    WIND   1124     2 2018-01-01
## # ... with 2,438 more rows
```

**HOWEVER**

When called from a browser context, it uses an XSLT style sheet to transform the data to make that table. We can just mimic that, too, vs process XML. It's a bit faster but you get a "wide" data frame vs a "long" one:

```
library(xml2)
library(xslt)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

doc <- read_xml("http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputbyFuelHourly/PUB_GenOutputbyFuelHourly.xml")

xsl <- read_xml("http://reports.ieso.ca/docrefs/stylesheet/GenOutputbyFuelHourly_HTML_t1-1.xsl")

xml_xslt(doc, xsl) %>% 
  html_node(xpath=".//table[contains(., 'HYDRO')]") %>% 
  html_table(header=TRUE, fill=TRUE) %>% 
  tbl_df()
## # A tibble: 408 x 9
##          Date  Hour NUCLEAR   GAS HYDRO  WIND SOLAR BIOFUEL `Total Output`
##         <chr> <int>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>   <int>          <int>
##  1 2018-01-01     1   11671  1583  4152   992     0       3          18401
##  2 2018-01-01     2   11672  1192  4093  1124     0       1          18082
##  3 2018-01-01     3   11672  1040  4231  1265     0       0          18208
##  4 2018-01-01     4   11669  1041  3895  1369     0       0          17974
##  5 2018-01-01     5   11674  1004  3271  1848     0       0          17797
##  6 2018-01-01     6   11682  1048  3292  2022     0       0          18044
##  7 2018-01-01     7   11682   966  3977  2378     0       1          19004
##  8 2018-01-01     8   11682   741  4311  2542     0       4          19280
##  9 2018-01-01     9   11678   650  4058  2719     2       2          19109
## 10 2018-01-01    10   11682   556  4644  2687    13       2          19584
## # ... with 398 more rows
```

I'd (personally) be inclined to use the former (XML) method and work on refactoring the code to speed-up the transformation (I did it the "brute force" way) since it's actual "data".

But, the latter works and is faster and may be in a format you need without further transformation.

Neither of these requires an extra, external dependency like RSelenium or splashr.

**UPDATE**

The OP's comment about the style sheet not being in Dev Tools on Chrome is 100% incorrect:

[image]

They likely didn't have Dev Tools up in Chrome before going to the URL.

Comment: i won't lie, method #2 is also more elegant and will be easier for me to look at a year from now. Thank you for the well-explained solution(s). One question - is there a particular method and/or place to look for the stylesheet? That is probably where i would've ended up banging my head against a wall for a couple hours.

Comment: Aye, #2 is def easier on the  :-) I pulled up the site while having Developer Tools open (Chrome, Safari & Firefox all have it; I think Edge does as well, now). The `.xslt` link showed up (IIRC) right after the `.xml` one in the list.

Comment: btw: `janitor::clean_names()` can make quick work of those semi-bad column names (I usually include that but forgot to this time)

Comment: if anyone comes across this excellent xslt solution in the future, I just want to note that at least in chrome, I didn't find the stylesheet href in the dev tools - rather, i had to use the "view page source" option, and then (as hrbmstr says) it's right there at the top.

Comment: all good. i didn't say it wasn't there, i said i didn't find it.